# Unable to setState array of objects - Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate

I'm a newbie to TypeScript. I'm trying to update the state of an array of objects.

the array of objects:

```
const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState<any[]>([
    {
      id: '1',
      q: 100,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      q: 50,
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      q: 50,
    },
  ]);
```

I'm updating this array using theis function that I use to update the array.
The function works correctly and returns the correct answer. (result should be the new state)

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';    
export const updateProductQuantity = (
      products: any[],
      id: any,
      operation: 'increase' | 'decrease',
      minValue: number
    ) => {
      const index = products.findIndex((product) => product.id === id);
      let updatedQuantity, newQuantities;
      if (operation === 'increase') {
        updatedQuantity = products[index].q + 1;
      } else {
        updatedQuantity = products[index].q - 1;
        let newValue = updatedQuantity - 1;
        if (minValue && newValue < minValue) return;
      }
      const updatedProduct = { id: id, q: updatedQuantity };
      newQuantities = update(products, {
        $splice: [[index, 1, updatedProduct]],
      });
      return newQuantities;
    };
```

And here I update the state.

```
const newQuantities = updateProductQuantity(quantity, id, 'increase', 1);
setQuantity(newQuantities);
```

P.S. The parameters are passed correctly

I'm getting error at this line:

```
setQuantity(newQuantities);
```

Here is the error:

```
Argument of type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<any[]>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<any[]>'.  TS2345
```

Comment: what is the `newQuantities`? add it to the question (need to console.log(newQuantities))

Answer (score 0):

That's because your function might return undefined.
You can update your useState hook to

```js
const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState<any[] | undefined>([
    {
      id: '1',
      q: 100,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      q: 50,
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      q: 50,
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: When I update it like that, I get another error. 

Argument of type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

This error pops up for each place where I use quantity array